# Can't copy text within a link with an ID as an href

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, anchor, vendor-prefix

I have text within links that have IDs as their href properties, for e.g.  and if someone tries to copy the text inside, it drags the whole link out in a little popup, see image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sicHn.png

On Chrome, I found that -webkit-user-modify:read-write gets rid of this error, and -moz-user-modify:read-write works on Firefox, but I cannot find a fix for IE. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the contenteditable attribute is defaulted to false, and if you add contenteditable=true you can copy the text within ID a tags